# String comparison in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to compare to bits of string in Elixir - if they're equal then the `if` block fires or the `else` block should fire.

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    Logger.info id
    Logger.info "----------"
    Logger.info conn.assigns.current_user
    if conn.assigns.current_user == id do
        professional = Repo.get!(Professional, id)
        render(conn, "show.html", professional: professional)
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in for that!")
      |> redirect(to: site_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
```

In the above, `Logger.info id` and `Logger.info conn.assigns.current_user` both return the same thing, but the `if` block is never entered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the following, `if conn.assigns.current_user === id do` ?

Comment: @Chris  - Yes.. `==` and `===` behave the same way in this snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your `conn.assigns.current_user` is a number and `id` is a string. `IO.inspect(is_binary(conn.assigns.current_user))`

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on the other answer, but the better way to check your params is with guards, `when is_binary(id)` guards against nils

Comment: Then just parse the int.

Answer (score 2):

As greg said, it is most likely that your id in the params is a string, so you would have to make sure you are comparing the same types of objects.
I would avoid parsing to integer though, because it can yield some unexpected result for example if your id is nil.

I'm not an expert in elixir, but here are a few solutions I can think of:

```
# String interpolation will automatically cast the interpolated values to string
if "#{conn.assigns.current_user}" == "#{id}" do

# Casting to char list can handle nil values as well as strings and integers
if to_char_list(conn.assigns.current_user) == to_char_list(id) do

# Regular to_string
if to_string(conn.assigns.current_user) == to_string(id) do
```

Comment: Copied here for the sake of entropy constancy. @greg says: “ the better way to check your params is with guards, when `is_binary(id)` guards against `nils`,”—that is true.

Answer (score 2):

Multiline `if` is a code smell in 99% of cases. Your snippet might be rewritten as:

```
case to_string(conn.assigns.current_user) do
id ->
  render(conn, "show.html", professional: Repo.get!(Professional, id))
_ ->
  conn
  |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in for that!")
  |> redirect(to: site_path(conn, :index))
  |> halt()
end
```

I have put this as an answer just to show the approach, the answer by @greg is still better.

Single-line `if`s are often used as ternaries in other languages, though:

```
if a < 42, do: "tiny", else: "huge"
```

Comment: Not sure where to comment now ^^ I agree that using ```if``` is not a very elixir way to solve the problem, however you would still want to parse to string, not to Integer, since Integer.parse/1 will return ```{result, rest}``` and String.to_integer/1 is a very strong assumption of the objects type, right?

Comment: @Ninigi What to parse and parse rules are defined by the task and are not 100% clear to me in this case. It looks like `to_string` is a best approach here.

Comment: OK thanks, just making sure I am not totally on the wrong track here :)

Comment: @Ninigi BTW, `case Integer.parse(id) do {current_user, _} -> ...` would work pretty fine as well. Your examples have a glitch of returning `true` for e.g. `nil` and empty binary. The only one operand should be cast.

Comment: Integer.parse/1 pretty much assumes you are using Integer for ids though, which is not the case for, lets say, mongodb. That's why I don't really like the idea of casting to int, instead of string :)